# IE scraping VBA code, example flight info search

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

Very grateful if you can help me to build /fix the below code to search for flight info from https://www.webjet.com.au/flights/ using VBA IE DOM. 

Let's assume I'm looking for flight on the 30 may from Dubai to London.

A) first I'm able to fill the city but it's not chosen from the saved dropdown internal list
B) how to populate date and other info (number of traveller, class) from dropdown list?

```
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim htmlbuttons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim htmlbutton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim htmlAs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim htmlA  As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate ("https://www.webjet.com.au/flights/")

Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Debug.Print ie.LocationName, ie.LocationURL

Set htmldoc = ie.Document

Set htmlInput = htmldoc.getElementById("departure-airport")

htmlInput.Value = "Dubai" 
'     << need help here how input will search for full city and airport name from its drop down list

Set htmlInput = htmldoc.getElementById("destination-airport")
htmlInput.Value = "london" ' << need help here how input will search for full city and airport name from its drop down list

'      ** addional code needed to choose number of passenger, class and date.

For Each htmlA In htmlAs   ' this code to choose one way or two way which is fine..

    If i = 32 Then
        htmlA.Click
        Exit For
    End If

    i = i + 1
Next htmlA

Set htmlbutton = htmldoc.getElementById("search-btn")
htmlbutton.Click
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**XHR:**

You could use xhr and mimic the POST request the page makes to retrieve flight info. Your choices e.g. number of adults, destination..... go in the POST body. You get a json response with all the info in. I use [this](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) json parser to handle the response and generate the json object to work with.

Explore the json response [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=628bc33b53d1498f8e047508cc8eac00).

Below is for 1 adult out and return, Dubai all airports, London all airports selected, economy. You can concatenate the values in for your search criteria.

---

Snapshot comparison of json returned from POST request (showing part for leg 1 of flight to London via Kigali

[image]

---

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetFlights()
'install code from https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas  to a module in project
'VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim json As Object
    Dim body As String
    body = "{""TripType"":""Return"",""Adults"":""1"",""Children"":""0"","
    body = body & """Infants"":""0"",""Class"":""Economy"","
    body = body & """FlightStops"":[{""CityFromCode"":""DXB"",""CityToCode"":""LON"",""DepartureDate"":""2019-05-30"",""ReturnDate"":""2019-06-01"",""TsaAirportFromCode"":""DXBALL"",""TsaAirportToCode"":""LON""}],"
    body = body & """ShowMixAndMatch"":false,""Locale"":""en-AU""}"

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", "https://flights.webjet.com.au/api/HybridSearch/GetFlightSearchResults?instart_disable_injection=true", False
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*"
        .send body
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
    End With
    Stop
End Sub
```

---

**Internet Explorer:**

You can set the dates via javascript  (in order for entry to be retained)

```
 Option Explicit    
'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub GetPrices()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.webjet.com.au/flights/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
           With .querySelector("#departure-airport")
               .Focus
               .Value = "Dubai, United Arab Emirates - All Airports (DXB)"
           End With

           Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

           With .querySelector("#destination-airport")
               .Focus
               .Value = "London, United Kingdom - All Airports (LON)"
           End With

           Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

           With .querySelector("#ft-dates-return")
               .Focus
               .Value = "Thu 30 May 2019 - Tue 4 Jun 2019"
               .FireEvent "onchange"
           End With

           .parentWindow.execScript "document.querySelector('#ft-hidden-check-in-date-return').value = 'Thu 30 May 2019';"
           .parentWindow.execScript "document.querySelector('#ft-hidden-check-out-date-return').value = 'Tue 4 Jun 2019';"
           .parentWindow.execScript "document.querySelector('#ft-hidden-popover-date-return').value = 'Thu 30 May 2019 - Tue 4 Jun 2019';"

           Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

           .querySelector("#zsl-button-search").Click
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

With adults, children....

```
Option Explicit

'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub GetPrices()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, ie As New InternetExplorer
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Const ADULTS As Long = 2
    Const CHILDREN As Long = 2
    Const INFANTS As Long = 1 'infants cannot be greater than number of adults
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.webjet.com.au/flights/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
           With .querySelector("#departure-airport")
               .Focus
               .Value = "Dubai, United Arab Emirates - All Airports (DXB)"
           End With

           Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

           With .querySelector("#destination-airport")
               .Focus
               .Value = "London, United Kingdom - All Airports (LON)"
           End With

           Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

           With .querySelector("#ft-dates-return")
               .Focus
               .Value = "Thu 30 May 2019 - Tue 4 Jun 2019"
               .FireEvent "onchange"
           End With

           .parentWindow.execScript "document.querySelector('#ft-hidden-check-in-date-return').value = 'Thu 30 May 2019';"
           .parentWindow.execScript "document.querySelector('#ft-hidden-check-out-date-return').value = 'Tue 4 Jun 2019';"
           .parentWindow.execScript "document.querySelector('#ft-hidden-popover-date-return').value = 'Thu 30 May 2019 - Tue 4 Jun 2019';"

           Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

           .querySelector("#button-passengers .zsl-caret-down").Click

           Do
               .querySelector("[aria-label='Increase adult passengers']").Click
           Loop Until .querySelector("#number-of-adults") = ADULTS

           Do
               .querySelector("[aria-label='Increase child passengers 2-11 years old']").Click
           Loop Until .querySelector("#number-of-children") = CHILDREN

           Do
               .querySelector("[aria-label='Increase infant passengers less than 2 years old']").Click
           Loop Until .querySelector("#number-of-infants") = IIf(INFANTS > ADULTS, ADULTS, INFANTS)


           Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

           .querySelector("#zsl-button-search").Click
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: HI Qharr.. much appreciated. i am afraid the above solution is too complicated to digest with my modest programming knowledge ... i will very interest to see any IE.DOM solution which i am relatively familiar with.

Comment: Hi, the bottom one is IE Dom

Comment: Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Marklah, The suggestion given by QHarr can help to solve your issue. I suggest you to check it and if you think that it can solve your issue than I suggest you to mark his suggestion as an answer for this question. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of questions. If you have any further questions than you can let us know about that. We will try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT  i confirm the answer provided by Qharr answers my questions. Please advise how to mark it as the answer

Comment: Please refer this link will guide you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @QHarr do we actually  need  "Dim html As HTMLDocument and  Set html = New HTMLDocument" in the above ? as i dont see any uses of it above

Comment: No. That was a mistake.

Comment: @qharr. One last qs pls  and for my info . How can use parentWindow.execScript to click "#button-passengers .zsl-caret-down" button. Thanks

Comment: .document.parentWindow.execScript "document.querySelector('#button-passengers .zsl-caret-down').click();"

Comment: I was trying to repliate the exact code above on differernt website https://www.skyscanner.net but was not successful due to differet html elements.  Would u be able to provide me with the codes for skyscanner assuming one way ticket and one adult . Happy to open a seperate request  if needed. Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes open a new question and include your code attempt and explain where stuck. Also, check the Terms and Conditions of the website in case scraping is forbidden.